# How to hide text on titlebar?

Tags: fonts, appearance, text, titlebar

I want to change the height of title-bar, but until now (as I know) there's only one way to do that : change the font-size of WINDOWS TITLE FONT (in Appearance preferences). So far so good except the BIG SIZE of the text. How could I disable(or hide) the text?

Comment: Emerald themes can do that, but i guess you wouldn't want to use it, some themes for metacity also don't have the Text in the tittlebar.

Comment: Yes, I dont want to use Emerald. Just wondering that is there any way to modify a metacity theme (which file, which property or something like that)?

Comment: I'm not in Ubuntu now but i think in gconf-editor.
apps->metacity->general.

Comment: Or you can edit the theme, if you installed it through Gnome Appearance window the themes are here: home/[yourusername]/.themes/nameIchose/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml

Comment: And if you installed the themes through sudo apt-get, it's here:/usr/share/theme

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to edit the theme, if you installed them through the Gnome Appearance window the themes are here: `home/[yourusername]/.themes/nameIchose/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml`. And if you installed the themes through sudo apt-get, they're here: `/usr/share/theme`, you'll need to be root to make edits to the files there (use gksu nautilus).

Look for something like this:

`<frame_style name=...`

```
    <piece position="titlebar" ...
<piece position="title" draw_ops="title-..."/>`
```

It depends on the theme. Experiment and you'll get results.

Comment: It didnt work for me. I added has_title="false" and selected another theme (let's say Ambiance), then I selected my theme again, the windows border is still the last theme i chose (Ambiance) instead of the border of my theme. Seem that has_title="false" makes the theme have no border.